# Go back to original clone of repo

Tags: git, github, fork, git-commit

I am working on an open source project. I've forked the repo and have been working with it.

I want to create a pull request for the work I've done but all I need to do know is update the readme with a link to my work.

It seems like I can't fork a repo multiple times and I can't figure out how to go back to the original commit when I first forked the repo.

How do I get the original repo I forked and just update the readme to create a pull request?

Comment: it would probably be smarter not only to fork it, but to also work on a different branch (or at least a local clone), as you can do way more that way than on github only

Answer (score 0):

- add the initial GitHub repo as a remote to your local repo (e.g : you can name it `upstream`)
- fetch it : `git fetch upstream`

You will now be able to view the differences between your work and `upstream`